# WiFi physical layer (PHY) for STM32

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, wireless, ethernet, wifi

I have a STM32 uC that has an internal Ethernet controller.

If I want to use LAN I just buy some cheap PHY chip, RJ45 socket and it works.

What If I want Wi-Fi? **Is there any chip that can be placed as PHY to work with STM32 MAC Ethernet interface?**

Comment: No, the protocol is different.

Comment: How about esp8266 modules? They come for approx 2 USD and has everything that you need. Besides this, you get a uC clocked at 80/160 MHz, few gpio and some peripherals like UART and i2c.

Comment: Or you can use an ESP01 as a AT command controlled WiFi module and connect it to your STM32 via UART.

Comment: Can I buy somewhere only esp8266 chip? Not module, but sole chip? I don't want solder module to my PCB, I would rather integrate it as part of my PCB, but all I can see are only modules... 
Beside I need it to be fast, so UART is out of question. I will have a lot of measurements data to send.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I have found the chip. Hope I it fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The MII interface used to connect an Ethernet PHY to your STM32 microcontroller is specific to 10/100 Mbit Ethernet. It cannot be used for other types of devices.

Comment: Well, but in the end 2nd OSI layer (MAC) is transported by WiFi. I mean I you watch your WiFi in your PC by Wireshark you will see regular Ethernet frames. Maybe there is a chip to convert from MII to WiFi, with SPI (or like) configuration of WiFi (selecting networks, passwords etc).